# cloud composer giving error Maintenance operations: Required "container.operations.list" permission(s) for "projects

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-composer

I have created a composer Environemnt with private IP enabled, all the configurations are done properly but the environemnt is continously throwing error. Even I tried giving **Owner** permision to the Service account used i.e (Default compute Engine Service account) but no luck.

```
**"Maintenance operations: Required "container.operations.list" permission(s) for "projects/".**
```

[image]

I am running single DAG only, it is failing continously. The Environemnt goes to healthy state for sometime and again back to same error .

Need some input to resolve this issue . Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a GKE permission error. Can you try adding Kubernetes Engine Admin just to be safe? You can revoke this permission and choose a lower permission level if needed. You can visit this [link](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/access-control#recommendations) for more information.

[image]

Comment: I tried adding this permission but didnot help me to resolve.